# Exists function

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, where-clause

I am trying to answer the following query

write a query that shows flight no (flno), origin and destination for all flights where there exists another flight that goes back from the destination to the origin.

```
select distinct flno, origin, destination as d from flight 
where exists (select flno, destination from flight where origin = d)
```

The first two answers are correct but it gives me more answers which does not relate to the question?

Flight Table:

[image]

Comment: you're not checking the destination of the flight in the `exists` clause

Comment: Sorry, I am still a bit confused? Am I not suppose to check the destination to the origin again?

Comment: if you're looking at a Detroit - New York flight, you need to confirm that there exists a New York - Detroit flight. You need to match the destination to the origin and the origin to the destination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *correlate* the subquery in the `exists` condition with the outer query. The logic you appears seems to be:

```
select flno, origin, destination
from flight f
where exists (
    select 1 
    from flight f1 
    where f1.origin = f.destination and f1.destination = f.origin
)
```

Comment: Thank you. While the answer is correct I still do not understand your query. But I will try to figure it out backwards. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way to solve the above query without using subquery:

```sql
select flno, origin, destination from flight f1, flight f2 
where fl.origin = f2.destination and f1.destination = f2.origin
```

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately I was asked to use a sub query.